# Calculated Column in Sharepoint List that allows for manual entry

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am not sure if this is possible or not. I have a dropdown box in a Sharepoint List that is for Grant Type. If "SAG & ESSRS" are selected, I want another column to appear where you can then enter in a submission number. Is this possible or can you only create calculated columns in Sharepoint? This might be too complicated to implement but thought I would ask.

At the moment I have a calculated column with an IF formula to determine if they have one or the other, but it doesn't allow manual entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can have columns be conditionally shown as part of the SharePoint list form. You do this by:

1. Open a list item to show the form
2. Open the form customization menu and choose **Edit columns**:

   [image]
3. Using the context menu (3 dots) on the column you want to conditionally show, choose **Edit conditional formula**:

[image]

4. The conditional formula just needs to evaluate to true or false (true when visible, false when hidden). Since you want it to only be shown when Grant Type has a value of `SAG & ESSRS` you can use this formula:

`=[$GrantType]=='SAG & ESSRS'`

[image]

Keep in mind the following:

- Conditional Formulas cannot be applied to required columns
- You can string multiple conditions together using or (`||`)
- The internal name of the column is what is used between the `[$` and `]` which I've assumed to be `GrantType`
- This has nothing to do with calculated fields
- This is only available in SharePoint Online using the modern experience
- This has no effect on Grid View (Quick Edit) editing. If that's a problem, you can turn this off in list settings

Comment: This is brilliant, this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much for the answer, it was really helpful.

Comment: Sorry I have not been online lately. I apologise for the late reply.